# How do I start tor that is resident on a usb?

Tags: usb, launcher, browser, tor

I downloaded tor and extracted it to my desktop. I can run tor using ./start-tor-browser.

I want to run tor from a usb, so I can carry it with me - one of tor's advertised advantages.

I moved the directory tor-browser_en-US to a usb ('usb') at /media/user/usb.

I cannot get ./start-tor-browser to execute; either from the directory it is in, or from home, using the path to the file. I cannot get the file to be executable, in the above directory. I tried using sudo, and tried to directly access/modify file properties.

I also tried to start tor using the file icon accessed via the usb folder icon on the desktop. No go. Hitting 
start-tor-browser.desktop 
produced a message telling me that the code is an untrusted launcher. No option to proceed was provided.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Tim

Comment: Maybe it is better to use [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) than to try to make Tor work in Ubuntu.

Comment: sudodus: To solve this issue, I will install Tails. My goal was to be able to use tor on machines everywhere, but it was pointed out to me that memory swaps can lead to info from the usb being left on the computer(s). I don't know if that is correct, but I will act on it by using Tails.

Comment: sudodus: My more general question, and why I posted on "ask ubuntu" is that I would like to run executables that reside on usb drives. How can that be done, unless I can make files on usb drives (/media/user/drive/code) executable?

Comment: In general, you can install programs (and make them survive reboot) in a persistent live system and in an installed system. Both kinds of systems are possible on USB drives. But I don't know the details of Tails. Please visit its web site, and look for information about it, [Tails - Support](https://tails.boum.org/support/index.en.html). - Tails is off-topic here at AskUbuntu, so we cannot give you much more ...

Comment: sudodus: I installed Tails on a usb, and all is good. Thank you for the guidance.